# calling ng-show on specific element based on parameter (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my menu I have a lot of buttons that open submenus.

Since I don't want a massive switch in my code that checks which button is pressed and which menu to animate I wanted to try the following:
In the **HTML** I call the function toggleVis with as a parameter the name of the element to be toggled:

```
<ul class="sidebar-bottom-list" ng-controller="MenuController">
<li>
    <a href="#/dossier" ng-click="toggleVis(showSubmenuDos); go('/dossier')" ng-class="class" class="sidemenuItem"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open">&nbsp;</span>Dossiers</a>
    <div class="list-group narrow-list-group no-padding-bottom slider-top-bottom" ng-show="showSubmenuDos" ng-class="active">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="dosMenuItems(0)">lijst</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="dosMenuItems(1)">algemeen</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="dosMenuItems(2)">partijen</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="dosMenuItems(3)">documenten</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="dosMenuItems(4)">notas</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="dosMenuItems(5)">royementen</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="dosMenuItems(6)">urenregistratie</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="dosMenuItems(7)">voortgang</a>
    </div>
</li>
<!-- imagine more menu items like this one -->
```

Then in my **main.js** I have the toggleVis function like this:

```
app.controller('MenuController', function($scope, $location) {

//can be triggered by ng-click="go('/path')"
$scope.go = function(path) {
    $location.path(path);
};

//toggle visibillity
$scope.toggleVis = function(param) {
    //$scope.{param} = !$scope.{param}
    alert(param)
    $scope.param = !$scope.param;
    //param.ngShow = !param.ngShow;
    //$scope.this = !$scope.this;
}
});
```

As you can see I have tried some things, but nothing works.
Is there a way to do what I want, or is there a way to do this even better?
I am looking for a well explained answer.

Comment: Try $scope[param] instead of $scope.param

Comment: If you put a name in, then surround it in single quotes: `toggleVis('showSubmenuDos')` that way it will be passed in as a string.. but I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve , there maybe an easier way, if you can post a plnker

Comment: What is `showSubmenuDos` bound to? Shouldn't there be an `ng-repeat` in here somewhere? Otherwise, even if this was to work, the second call to `toggleVis` would just toggle visibility for all items

Comment: Graham: showSubmenuDos is bound to the ng-show of the first menu item, the second menu item would have another name like showSubmenuRel which will then be parsed to the toggleVis function and so on..
Callum: I have tried that but this line: $scope.param = !$scope.param; won't work if the param is a string, I will try to make a plunker

Comment: turned out the combination of Yalambers and Callums comment was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to toggle views is the below example. Just switch value on click with `var = !var` and combine this with `ng-show`:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <button ng-click="show = !show">Toggle</button>
  <p ng-show="show">I am getting shown and hidden!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer DonJuwe, but the ng-show is not the only action bound to the ng-click and I find it very messy if there is a lot of code in the ng-click element, and I want to be able to call the show from everywhere in my site and show the right menu based on the parameter i'm giving the function